# Panning of a SVG Slow on larger Zoomfactor

Tags: google-chrome, svg, css-transforms

I have a HTML site which uses a SVG graphic, which is zoomed and panned via a CSS transform.

This works very smoothly with a zoomfactor of 1.2

With a zoomfactor of 1.8, it's getting very slow.

Answer (score 0):

We're facing the same problem. We print a ground plan from CAD to svg in our HTML-site. When you zoom out all the vectors are shown and the pan and zoom is smooth. If you zoom in and one can only see a little amount of the vectors it is very very slow. Very strange...
And we are not really sure but the problem seemed to occur with a new chrome-version. Before it worked well.

Comment: In V65 it's fixed. But FF is still much faster